# NoClassDefFoundError in executable jar if i use the Paths class

Tags: executable-jar

I used the class "Paths" to work with a file. I added the "rt.jar" to my classpath and i export my application as "executable jar". The issue is that the "rt.jar" is not in my exported jar and i get NoClassDefFoundError if i run the jar.

Comment: `rt.jar` is part of a Java Installation, it does not belong inside your jar.

Comment: Ok, that is the reason that the rt.jar is not in my executable jar but why i get NoClassDefFoundError if it is in the java installation?

Comment: The JDK what i use is JDK1.6.0_45. This is requiered from an external api.jar